# How long to wait before Humble Bundle games appear in Software Centre?

Tags: software-center

At software-center.ubuntu.com it says

> Thank you for downloading your Humble Bundle games from the Ubuntu Software Center
>
> Notes: As these games have been recently added to Ubuntu Software Center it might take a minute for them to appear. If you see a "Not found" message, Ubuntu Software Center is working in the background to update the list of available apps.

When I click on a link, the software centre opens and it says `There isn’t a software package called “swordandsworcery” in your current software sources`. I have waited for about 30 minutes now. I have also executed `sudo apt-get update` & restarted software centre to no avail.

Do I keep waiting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can speed up the process by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo update-apt-xapian-index
```

It runs manually what the Software Center does at regular intervals.

Then start the Software Center, the games should be there.

Comment: It was working when I next checked my PC. However, this answer seems legit. Thanks. ;)